# How to schedule item backup?

Tags: packages, scheduler-job

We would like to schedule a item backup(package) on specific time. Is it possible to create a package of the items while scheduling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with Sitecore Powershell Extensions.

Packaging with SPE - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/packaging

Then create a task scheduler to run this powershell script - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/tasks

Answer (score 2):

To create Sitecore Package programmatically performs below steps which described by **Hishaam Namooya** in one of his articles. I am giving you the reference of that article as well:

1. First step is to create a new Package Project

```
var packageProject = new PackageProject
{
    Metadata =
    {
        PackageName = "Specify the package name",
        Author = "Specify the author name",
        Version = "Specify the version",
        Publisher = "Specify the Publisher"
    }
};
```

2. Provide the package with the source of the items or files.

```
//Creating Source for Files
var packageFileSource = new ExplicitFileSource
{
    Name = "File Source Name"
};

//Creating Source for Items
var packageItemSource = new ExplicitItemSource
{
    Name = "Item Source Name"
};
```

3. Instantiate a new Source collection and add the item source to the source collection.

```
//Instantiate a new SourceCollection
var sourceCollection = new SourceCollection();

//Add the Item Source to the SourceCollection
sourceCollection.Add(packageItemSource);
```

4. Include the sub-items

```
//Include subitem. You may have a method to set the include subitem.
var includeSubItem = "true / false";

var itemUri = Factory.GetDatabase("master).Items.GetItem("path to item");

if (itemUri != null)
{
    if (includeSubItem.Equals("true"))
    {
        sourceCollection.Add(new ItemSource()
        {
            SkipVersions = true,
            Database = itemUri.Uri.DatabaseName,
            Root = itemUri.Uri.ItemID.ToString()
        });
    }
    else
    {
        packageItemSource.Entries.Add(new ItemReference(itemUri.Uri, false).ToString());
    }
}
```

5. Map the directory path and generate the package.

```
var pathMapped = MainUtil.MapPath("Your File Path");

packageFileSource.Entries.Add(pathMapped);
```

```
if (packageFileSource.Entries.Count > 0)
{
    packageProject.Sources.Add(packageFileSource);
}

if (packageItemSource.Entries.Count > 0 || sourceCollection.Sources.Count > 0)
{
    packageProject.Sources.Add(sourceCollection);
}

packageProject.SaveProject = true;

using (var writer = new PackageWriter(MainUtil.MapPath("Path to save package")))
{
    Context.SetActiveSite("shell");

    writer.Initialize(Installer.CreateInstallationContext());

    PackageGenerator.GeneratePackage(packageProject, writer);

    Context.SetActiveSite("website");
}
```

**See the blog post for more detail and reference:** [SITECORE CREATE PACKAGE PROGRAMMATICALLY](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/11/07/sitecore-create-package-programmatically/)

Now regarding the schedule of the same code, you can check the series of the articles with the below links:

1. [Sitecore Scheduler: Part](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/04/sitecore-scheduler.html)-1
2. [Create and Configure Scheduler in Sitecore: Part-2](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/04/create-scheduler-is-sitecore-database.html)
3. [Pass Sitecore Items in .Net Class with Scheduler: Part-3](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/04/pass-sitecore-items-in-net-class-with.html)